# Why does plugging a hole in an airplane's fuselage result in a huge (10x) atmospheric pressure spike?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, atmospheric-science, rigid-body-dynamics

While reading about uncontrolled decompression, I came across one famous airline incident, [Aloha Airlines Flight 243](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243), where the article I was reading [discussed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_decompression#A_small_hole_will_blow_people_out_of_a_fuselage) a 1-square-foot hole created in the fuselage of the plane, a woman being subsequently sucked into that hole (and, I assume, "plugging" it). According to the article:

> this would have caused a 10 atmosphere pressure spike, hence the much greater material failure.

The greater material failure in question here is an 18ft x 25ft hole in the fuselage, caused by this huge spike in atmospheric pressure. I'm assuming this means ten times the normal atmospheric pressure.

My question is, why would the woman's body plugging the 1x1 hole create an atmospheric pressure spike, let alone one of such magnitude?

Comment: Note: I added the rigid dynamics tag because we are dealing with a rigid structure (an airplane), and the fluid dynamics tag because I'm guessing we are dealing with air, which is a fluid (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument is that the air was flowing through the hole at around 700 mph, so the air inside the aircraft had a substantial velocity in the direction of the hole. The air velocity inside the plane would have been less than 700 mph because the flow was converging on the hole, but the speed of the air would still have been hundreds of mph.

When the hole was blocked the air inside the plane carried on moving towards the (now blocked) hole due to its own inertia. Although we think of air as light it has a mass of around 1.25kg per cubic metre. So a single cubic metre of air moving at 700 mph has the same momentum as me (68kg) moving at about 13 mph. If I hit a wall at 13 mpg there would be quite a thud. And that's just a single cubic metre.

So the pressure spike is simply because all the air heading towards the hole carried on  moving after the hole was blocked and the force due to the momentum of all that air raised the pressure near the hole.